# Removing selective row from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('DatasetDemo.csv', index_col='ID')
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    COL_1  REL_1  COL_2  REL_2  COL_3  REL_3  COL_4  REL_4
ID                                                        
1    12.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    10.0    NaN   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3     NaN   12.0    NaN   12.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0
5    12.0    NaN   12.0    NaN   12.0    NaN   12.0    NaN
6     NaN   10.0    NaN   10.0    NaN   10.0    NaN   10.0
```

[image: demo dataset]

How can I delete row numbers, 2, 3, 5 and 6 as shown in the image? As those rows have no values which have column COL_%d and REL_%d together, as in row 1, in which COL_1 and REL_1 have value together.

PS: There are many numbers of columns which are in pair like COL_%d and REL_%d, for example more columns such as: COL_5 | REL_5 | COL_6 | REL_6 | ....

and there are thousands of rows.

Comment: I am sorry. I am editing it now. @Ch3steR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with *Numpy* if `COL_%d` and `REL_%d` are always adjacent to each other i.e. `[COL_1, REL_1, COL_2, REL_2, ...]`, if columns are arent in this order use @jezrael's answer.

```
# df = df.set_index('ID')
arr = df.to_numpy()
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, 2) # This furthur divides our
                                            # columns  into chunks of size 2
# Now, we have to find if both `COL_%d` and `REL_%d` are both not NaN
m = (~np.isnan(reshaped_arr)).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
df[m]

    COL_1  REL_1  COL_2  REL_2  COL_3  REL_3  COL_4  REL_4
ID                                                        
1    12.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0
```

#### Explanation

```
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, 2)
# Our aim is group adjacent 2 values
print(reshaped_arr)

# [[[12.0, 10.0], [nan, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]],
#  [[10.0, nan], [10.0, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]],
#  [[nan, 12.0], [nan, 12.0], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]],
#  [[10.0, 12.0], [10.0, 12.0], [10.0, 12.0], [10.0, 12.0]],
#  [[12.0, nan], [12.0, nan], [12.0, nan], [12.0, nan]],
#  [[nan, 10.0], [nan, 10.0], [nan, 10.0], [nan, 10.0]]]

# Now we grouped adjacent value, we need to find if both values in one grp
# are nan values or not

m = (~np.isnan(reshaped_arr)).all(axis=2)

# [[ True, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, False],
#  [ True,  True,  True,  True],
#  [False, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, False]]

# now we've to find if there's any True in each row.
m = m.any(axis=1)
# [ True, False, False,  True, False, False]

# Use m for boolean indexing
df[m]
```

Timeit results:

```
# @jezrael's
In [51]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = df.filter(like='COL_').isna()
    ...: df2 = df.filter(like='REL_').isna()
    ...: df[(df1.to_numpy() == df2.to_numpy()).all(axis=1)]

926 µs ± 37.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# @Ch3ster's
In [52]: %%timeit
    ...: arr = df.to_numpy()
    ...: reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(len(arr), -1, 2)
    ...: m = (~np.isnan(reshaped_arr)).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
    ...: df[m]

129 µs ± 9.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# @jezrael's 2nd
In [54]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = df.filter(like='COL_').isna().rename(columns= lambda x: x.split('
    ...: _')[1])
    ...: df2 = df.filter(like='REL_').isna().rename(columns= lambda x: x.split('
    ...: _')[1])
    ...: df[(df1 == df2).all(axis=1)]

1.44 ms ± 26.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This is *9X* and *11X* faster respectively. This is faster because we eliminate a lot of overhead because we leveraged on the fact that `COL` and `REL` are always adjacent to each other.

Comment: Yes, the columns are always adjacent to each other. But at `reshaped_arr`, I get error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size...`. I think my dataset is too large.

Comment: can you post output of `df.shape`? @Leprachon

Comment: `df.shape` => `(416291, 39)`

Comment: You have an odd number of columns. So have one column with either `COL_%d` without `REL_%d` or vice-versa

Comment: simply put you have columns like this `[col1, rel1, col2]` you have `rel2` missing. @Leprachon

Comment: No, I have ID + 38 other columns.

Comment: Then set `ID` as index and use my answer. `df = df.set_index('ID')`

Answer (score 3):

If there are all sorted pairs columns you can use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with test if missing values, then convert to numpy array, compare and get only rows with all `True`s per rows:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='COL_').isna()
df2 = df.filter(like='REL_').isna()
df = df[(df1.to_numpy() == df2.to_numpy()).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   COL_1  REL_1  COL_2  REL_2  COL_3  REL_3  COL_4  REL_4
1   12.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0
```

If not sure of ordering rename column for get values after `_` for same columns names in `df1` and `df2`, so is possible compare both:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='COL_').isna().rename(columns= lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
df2 = df.filter(like='REL_').isna().rename(columns= lambda x: x.split('_')[1])

df = df[(df1 == df2).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   COL_1  REL_1  COL_2  REL_2  COL_3  REL_3  COL_4  REL_4
1   12.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0   10.0   12.0
```